# Android Simulating input

Tags: android, simulate

I want to ask is it possible to simulate touchscreen event from background service ? 
The only library I found for android is http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html,but as far as I read its need adb. I want to write such service,but how can easy and fast simulate touch input,I want to make some kind of a joystick from hardware outside the phone where I want on button press to make same x,y coordinates click inside the game.
Which is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate input in your own app, or are you trying to inject events into arbitrary apps?

Comment: I have a IOIO-OTG board connected threw bluetooth with the phone,I want each time the button is pressed to simulate screen tap and hold as long the finger is pressing the button,and I want this simulation to work with games like Subway Surf,Jetpack joyride and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask is it possible to simulate touchscreen event from background service ?

No, for security reasons.

Comment: @ДимитърИванов: You can only get threads in your own app, not third-party apps. Affecting third-party apps requires custom Android builds, or possibly a custom device driver since you are dealing with a hardware accessory providing the input.

Comment: So how its joystick working then,or even the mouse I connect to my phone tablet ? Isnt there a way to get the root of view from some service and when I obtain it to do some tap ?

Comment: @ДимитърИванов: There are existing drivers for those, using standard Bluetooth HID. If you can teach your board to do Bluetooth HID, then that's another route for you. None of this has anything to do with a background service in an SDK app, though.

Comment: @ДимитърИванов: "Isnt there a way to get the root of view from some service and when I obtain it to do some tap ? " -- no, as those are in another process.

Comment: Ok so I pressume that is not possible to write driver which all users can use witout custom android build ? And what other choices do I have I mean is there a really hard way to do it ?

Comment: If its not possible to simulate what about parsing data to android system just like my device is a mouse,it is already builded inside the framework so any idea how to use it ?

Comment: @ДимитърИванов: "I pressume that is not possible to write driver which all users can use witout custom android build ?" -- it's conceivable that rooted device users can install device drivers. I have never researched this, and it's somewhat off-topic for StackOverflow. "what about parsing data to android system just like my device is a mouse" -- at best, you may be able to accomplish this while running as root. That's outside the scope of my expertise.

Comment: @ДимитърИванов: The XDA forums are usually good places to get answers to questions about rooting. http://android.stackexchange.com would be another.